# Save object after closing app and retrieve it when app run again

Tags: android

I have this object and I'd like to save it after closing app and retrieve it when app run again.

```
final LatLng CENTRAL_VIEW = new LatLng(24.205835,-20.753174);


        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(CENTRAL_VIEW)      // Sets the center of the map to Central View
        .zoom(6)                   // Sets the zoom
        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Any simple example for that? Thanks!

Comment: create file and store data when closing app and retrieve it when app run again.

Comment: @Vis why you want to store object?

Answer (score 0):

As Paresh said we can not store object in `SharedPreference` but we can modify our preference using some external library to get stored the object as I did. [CustomSharedPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501146/how-to-store-class-object-in-android-sharedpreference)

Try to use it.

Answer (score -1):

save your object into shared preferences and obtain after restarting the app....
Simple ..

Comment: Its not possible to store object inside `SharedPreferences`, but its for storing only simple values.

Comment: that's the different thing, i mean that is JSONObject. So we can convert JSONObject into String and we can store String value streight way.

Comment: gson.fromJson and gson.toJson can be used.

Comment: True. I already did in one of my project and it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

see this , it's may help you :

http://androidcodemonkey.blogspot.in/2011/07/store-and-get-object-in-android-shared.html

http://www.thetekblog.com/2012/09/android-store-objects-in-sharedperferences/

http://www.mediafire.com/?a9x1ebyw1bf8t62

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.