# Moving value to activity not being accessed immediately

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, bundle

Is it possible to pass a value in a putExtra or Bundle to be accessed later?

For example, in a standard putExtra you load up the intent with the values you want to pass over and then in the activity specified in the intent, you retrieve those values. Is it possible to store the values in the putExtra and retrieve them in another activity that is NOT the one specified in the intent?

For context, I am using google sign in for authentication. I want to store the user's account in a putExtra and use it later in the app, but not in the activity that follows from the sign on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `Application` or `MultiDexApplication` class to keep a `SharedPreference` that holds your data in `String` format
- Use `SharedPreference` at you `Activity` and follow similar procedure.
- This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501146/how-to-store-class-object-in-android-sharedpreference) might give you some mental picture.